# Most efficient way to recode these multiple if statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I know this is a ridiculous example, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to write this code. Each project gets different values added to it depending on what state it takes place in. This is just a small snippet. I could potentially want to extend this out for all 50 states, which would be a lot of if statements. I could dump this in a function, but then the function would still have all the if statements.

```
Projects = [['Project A', 'CT', '', ''], ['Project B', 'MA', '', ''], ['Project C', 'RI', '', '']]

for project in Projects:
    if project[1] == 'CT':
        project[2] = project[0] + project[1]
        project[3] = '222'
    elif project[1] == 'MA':
        project[2] = '123'
        project[3] = None
    elif project[1] == 'ME':
        project[2] = '12323'
        project[3] = '333'
    elif project[1] == 'RI':
        project[2] = 'asdf'
        project[3] = '3333'
print Projects
```

Comment: Instead of dumping the whole thing in a function, split it into several.  check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Comment: Why not have a mapping `{state: (project[2].impact, project[3].impact), ...}`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe. I'm not super familiar with mapping. Could you expand on that?

Comment: Just using dictionaries will resolve this unless you have a lot of variable based values (like `project[0] + project[1]`)

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a dictionary mapping:

```
for project in Projects:
    project[2:4] = {
        'CT': [project[0]+project[1], '222'],
        'MA': ['123', None],
        'ME': ['12323', '333'],
        'RI': ['asdf', '3333']
    }[project[1]]
```

removes all the `if`/`else`, and just deals with real data :)

As suggested by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe), it may be more efficient delaying the evaluation of the dictionary values with `lambda`s (at the cost of writing more):

```
for project in Projects:
    project[2:4] = {
        'CT': lambda: [project[0]+project[1], '222'],
        'MA': lambda: ['123', None],
        'ME': lambda: ['12323', '333'],
        'RI': lambda: ['asdf', '3333']
    }[project[1]]()
```

---

---

<sub>Edit: explanation for [user2242044](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2242044/user2242044):</sub>

<sub>consider the function:</sub>

```
def foo(x):
    print('*** foo(%s)' % x)
    return x
```

<sub>and see what happens when you do:</sub>

```
>>> {1: foo(1), 2: foo(2)}[1]
*** foo(1)
*** foo(2)
1
```

<sub>as you see, it computes **all** the values in dictionary, calling both `foo(1)` and `foo(2)`, for then just using the value of `foo(1)`.</sub>

<sub>With `lambda`s:</sub>

```
>>> {1: lambda: foo(1), 2: lambda: foo(2)}[1]()
*** foo(1)
1
```

<sub>the dictionary returns a function, and when you call the function, the value is computed, thus computing only the value of `foo(1)`</sub>

Comment: The downside of this is that it requires `project[0]+project[1]` to be calculated even for states where that value won't be used. Delaying evaluation (e.g. with `lambda`) might be more efficient.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Post an answer? Would be interesting to see.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if the computations done in  the dictionary construction are *heavy* that certainly is a good idea

Comment: @mescalinum. I'm always confused by `lambda`. Can you give a brief overview of what the second code block does differently.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment and mescalinum's answer, if some of the impacts on `project[2]` will be derived from other values in the `project`, you can put callable objects (e.g. by using [*`lambda` expressions*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)) in the dictionary:

```
IMPACTS = {
    'CT': (lambda project: project[0] + project[1], '222'),
    'MA': ('123', None),
    ...,
}
```

Then you can apply it like:

```
for project in Projects:
    two, three = IMPACTS[project[1]]
    try:
        project[2] = two(project)
    except TypeError:
        project[2] = two 
    project[3] = three
```

If some of `project[3]`'s values will vary, you can similarly make them callable in the dictionary and apply the same `try`/`except` logic (or `if callable(...)`) to filter those that need calling.